# Turning v-select into a v-textfield on selecting other in dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a dropdown which displays the users but in dropdown option i have other so that I can enter in the name of the user if it is not in the list. Is there a way to turn v-select to v-textfield on selecting others from the dropdown in vue.

I am using vuetify version 1.0

```
<template>
 <v-form :model='appliances' class="content-padding" ref='pdfInputs'>
   <v-select class="company-size-dropdown"
    :items="users"
    attach
    item-text='name'
    item-value='name'
    v-model="appliances.first_name"
    label="First Name"
    required>
   </v-select>
 </v-form>
<template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  components: {
      moment
  },
  data () {
    return {
      users: [James, Scott, William, Other],
      appliances: {
        first_name: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you try `v-if` to switch the fields like

```
<template>
 <v-form :model='appliances' class="content-padding" ref='pdfInputs'>
   <v-select class="company-size-dropdown" v-if="appliances.first_name!=='Other'"
    :items="users"
    attach
    item-text='name'
    item-value='name'
    v-model="appliances.first_name"
    label="First Name"
    required>
   </v-select>
   <v-textfield v-else v-model="appliances.first_name">
   </v-textfield>
 </v-form>
<template>
```

Comment: I tried it this way but the issue here is it changes to text field but I am not able to enter value in it. It is pre populated with Other and if i try to remove Other it turns back to a dropdown.

Comment: Then you can try `v-show` instead of `v-if` or any toggle method to just hide and show these fields. The method I suggested will remove the field. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code by Rijosh (Thanks, nice one), by adding a @keyup event to the text box. Hence `appliances.first_name` will only be updated only when the user press enter key after entering the new first name.

Please check the [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/PooLZgw?editors=1111)

```
<div v-if="appliances.first_name!=='Other'">
  <v-select class="company-size-dropdown"
    :items="users"
    attach
    item-text='name'
    item-value='name'
    v-model="appliances.first_name"
    label="First Name"
    required>
  </v-select>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <v-text-field 
    v-model="newItem" 
    label="First Name"
    v-on:keyup.enter="appliances.first_name = newItem">
  </v-text-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refined the code by Anees Hameed (Thanks, nice one too), by adding a @keyup.esc event to the text box, some rules to make it easier for users to understand, and autofocus for when a user selects 'Other' to not lose focus.

```html
<v-select
  v-if="item !== 'Other'"
  v-model="item"
  :items="[...new Set(items.concat(item).filter(Boolean)), 'Other']"
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'This field is required']"
  label="My field"
  required
/>
<v-text-field
  v-else
  v-model="newItem"
  :rules="[
    v => !!v || 'This field is required',
    v => 'Other' === v || 'Fill in this field, and press enter'
  ]"
  autofocus
  label="My field"
  required
  @keyup.enter="item = newItem"
  @keyup.esc="item = null"
/>
```